# Can I make and test PS Vita games without registration?

Tags: unity

I am currently not registered as a Playstation Developer at the moment, but I have emailed Sony in the mean time to ask how a single person can register as an Indie Developer to publish. But can I still make my game in the mean time?

I have Unity and I know that Unity has Playstation support, so is there any chance that I can test my current game on PS Vita as well without registering with Sony first? That way, when I do register, the game can be closer to release.

Comment: Especially if you're using something like Unity, there's always a fair bit you can do even without being able to put the thing on a device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer from an email from Sony. In order to deploy from Unity, you do have to sign up as a registered developer as the SDKs from Sony have to be present.