# Do I Need To Purchase a Developer Kit from Sony to deploy from Unity?

Tags: unity, deployment

I want to make PS Vita games, and starting today, I will sign up as a registered developer with Sony so I can make my indie game for Android available on PS Vita, but i had a question.

I know that Unity can deploy to the Vita as long as I have Sony's SDKs, but would I need to purchase a physical Developer Kit from Sony in order to do this, or can I just deploy and test on my personal PS Vita? I cannot afford the Dev Kit so I really hope that I can just deploy to my own personal Vita.

Comment: In what is this question different from the [other](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126317/can-i-make-and-test-ps-vita-games-without-registration) you posted yesterday?

Comment: On that one, I was asking if I can deploy without registering at all with Sony. I found out though that I DO need to register and I'll delete that question soon. This one is specifically about hardware. A person from Sony emailed me he answer and told me that I do have to register for it and use the SDKs.

Comment: You should _not_ delete the other: if you have the answer, post an answer to it, and mark is as accepted :) It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions :)

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer on the Unity Forums. When PlayStation Mobile was still alive, you could test on a Retail Vita, but now that is not the case. You are required to use a PS Vita Developer Kit in order for Unity to deploy and test.

Comment: You'd have to use a dedicated Dev Kit bought from Sony themselves. It has special hardware and software made just for development. Back when PS mobile was still alive though, you could just use any old vita just lying around. But that isn't the case anymore.